# How to format string with many placeholders and one value

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have a string template that can be changed and only one value which I want to insert in all placeholders. For example:

```
String str = "He%s%so, wor%sd";
String value = "L";
```

I know that I can do next:

```
String.format(str, value, value, value);
```

But what if this string changed, how I can format it without changing my code?

Comment: Is there a realistic scenario behind this? Because if you change the string, then you'd change the parameters at the same time. Unless you get the string as input from somewhere, but then I'd take a good look at how you want to design your program.

Comment: What about `str.replace("%s", value)`

Comment: Ah, I simply forgot about this :)

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, I get a string as input from the resource file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use **%1$s** instead of **%s** like this:

```
String str = "He%1$s%1$so, wor%1$sd";
String value = "L";
System.out.println(String.format(str, value)); //HeLLo, worLd
```

Actually, you can use %2, %3... to specific the index of param:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%2$s --- %1$s", "A", "B")); //B --- A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already thought string.replace is a solution. I did not know about this feature in String.format. Additionally thanks about %2, %3..